# Web Scrapping with Python. I cant find the element that I'm looking for in the html

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I want to get the information of the born date of a tenis player given a specific link from the atp website. I want to complete a database with a new column of the born dates of the players. I have their link from the ATP website. There are 1662 unique players so im trying to do a web scraping code to save some hard hours of doing it by hand.

The code that im doing is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

player_link="https://www.atptour.com/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/player-activity?year=all&matchType=Singles"

def get_birthdate(player_link):
    # Make a GET request to the player's ATP Tour profile page
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.137 Safari/537.3"}

    response = requests.get(player_link, headers=headers)

    # Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find the birthdate element on the page and extract the text
    birthdate_element = soup.find("span", {"class": "table-birthday"})
    
    if birthdate_element is not None:
        birthdate = birthdate_element.text.strip()
        return birthdate
    else:
        print("Birthdate element not found on the page")
        return None
    
get_birthdate(player_link)
```

The output indicates that it didnt found the birthdate. When I try to inspect the website in chrome, I can see where it is, but the code doesnt indentifies where it is.

I tried to run another code to see the html content, and in fact it is different to the one that I visualize in chrome.

```
# Create a headers dictionary with the user agent of Chrome 112.0.5615.137
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.137 Safari/537.3"}

response = requests.get(player_link, headers=headers)
html_content = response.text

print(html_content)
```

How can I access the born date of the player? Does it has anything to do with that chrome's output? How can I get that same output as I visualize when I inspect the website?

Comment: The problem is likely because you're using `requests`, which does not understand javascript, to fetch the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is using Cloudflare captcha so you need work around that (for example using the module [`cloudscraper`](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)).

Another possibility is try to read cached page by Google (but you need change the URL a little):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.atptour.com/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/overview'  # <-- change the URL to this
cache_URL = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search"

def get_data(link):
    hdr = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }
    params = {
        'q': 'cache:' + link
    }
    req = requests.get(cache_URL, headers=hdr, params=params)
    return req.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data(url), 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.table-big-value-birthday').text)
```

Prints:

```
(1987.05.22)
```